# insert loaded data using ajax into page source to insert them into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 3 `div`s that when the user clicks on each of them, a particular content of a form will load. till this part there is no problem, but after that, I can't insert them into mysql.

html:

```
  <div id="adds">
  <div onclick="show_content('value1',this)" class="add selected">first div</div>
  <div onclick="show_content('value2',this)" class="add">second div</div>
  <div onclick="show_content('value3',this)" class="add">third div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="add_form"></div>
        <?php
          if(!empty($error)) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(".error").html(" <?php echo $error;?> ");
           $(".error").slideDown(function(){
              $(this).animate({top: '50%'});
           });
           $(".error_back").fadeIn();
           $("body").css("overflow" , "hidden");
           setTimeout(function(){
           $(".error").animate({top: '-74px'}, function(){
              $(this).slideUp();
           });
           $(".error_back").fadeOut();
           $("body").css("overflow" , "auto");
           },2000);
        </script>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
```

and jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_content(type_name,selected){
    datastring = "type_name=" + type_name;
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "motor.php",
          data: datastring,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
              $("#add_form").hide().html(html).fadeIn();
          }
    });
          return false;
    }
    </script>
```

and php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['type_name'])) {
    if($_POST['type_name']=='value_1') {
        include('add_dore.php');
        if(isset($_POST['add_value_1_submit'])) {
            $value_1 = $_POST['value_1'];
            if(empty($value_1)) {
                $error = "inter value 1";
                }else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `value_1`(
                     'id' ,
                     'value_1' ,
                )VALUES(
                     NULL ,
                     '$value_1'
                )");
            }
        }
    }elseif($_POST['type_name']=='value_2') {
        include('value_2.php');
    }elseif($_POST['type_name']=='value_3') {
        include('value_3.php');
    }
}
```

*for now, I just wrote the data for value_1:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <label for="value_1">value title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value_1" <?php if(!empty($value_1)) echo "value=\"$value_1\""; ?> />
</form>
```

Comment: did not read it all, but you have `if(isset($_POST['add_value_1_submit'])) {` and `$_POST['value_1']`, but you are not sending a `add_value_1_submit` or `value_1` in your `$.ajax({...});` only `type_name`.

Comment: @Sean how can I do that ?

Comment: Simple way is to add them to your `datastring` ->  `datastring = "type_name=" + type_name + "&add_value_1_submit=true&value_1=value1";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I tell the ajax to go to the motor.php . and you know after that, we should do the insertions and etc in our first page. I wrote the insertion in motor page and it was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be in SQL query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `value_1`(
                 'id' ,
                 'value_1' ,
            )VALUES(
                 NULL ,
                 '$value_1'
            )"
```

If id is autoincrement then write query without it

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `value_1`(
                 'value_1' ,
            )VALUES(
                 '$value_1'
            )"
```

Comment: no. @Anton problem is included PHP file doesn't show in the page source to have processing and inserting into database. In the normal situation and without AJAX, included PHP file will insert into page source.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO value_1('id','value_1') VALUES('','".$value_1."')";
```

Comment: This answer is false, I think. And There is no problem with the database insertion code.

Comment: remove `return false` from jquery

Comment: In your sql u write `value_1('id','value_1',)` remove last `,` inside `( )`